# A mathematicians Riley riddle

Tags: riddle

A Riley riddle:

> My prefix is a unicorn,
> My infix is not better.
> My suffix is the first to do teamwork,
> My $whole + Boyz$ is hip-hop.

Can you solve this?
Sorry, you can't just go to a mathematician and ask him to solve this.
Only a Puzzler can solve this

Hint 1:

> The answer is not a word

Comment: Can mathematic puzzlers answer?

Comment: @Oliver Yes ;-)

Comment: The answer's something they like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 102

General Reasoning

> Given the title and the hint, I think the answer might be a number.

My prefix is a unicorn,

> A unicorn would indicate the number **1**

My infix is not better.

> I assume this to mean "not better than my prefix", so perhaps **0**.

My suffix is the first to do teamwork,

> There's no "I" in team so the first number which could be considered to do teamwork is probably **2**.

My ℎ+ is hip-hop.

> I think this refers to the group [102 Boyz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/102_Boyz)

Previous answer

> 112 which I thought might refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/112_(album))

Comment: Really, Really almost there. Just one digit wrong. But nice answer

Comment: This is nowhere near what I was thinking of!

Comment: @math I think I've found the answer you're looking for which fits a bit better.

Comment: Exactly. You are right.

Comment: rot13(Zl rkcynangvbaf sbe svefg 3 yvarf:
"Zl cersvk vf n havpbea"
Nyjnlf gnxr gur cersvk bs gur cersvk! Fb hav, fnzr nf 1.
"Zl vasvk vf abg orggre"
Gur abg fbhaqf yvxr anhtug, va Hx 0. Vs lbh ner abg pbaivaprq, chg n pbzzn nsgre abg. V gbyq lbh V nz gryyvat gur nafjre!;-)
"Zl fhssvk vf gur svefg gb qb grnzjbex,"
Va gur beqre bs Angheny ahzoref, 2 vf gur svefg ahzore juvpu pna qb grnzjbex, orpnhfr vg unf 2 cnegvpvcnagf be zber.)